# issue in saving or editing in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

`OledbCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type at system.data.common.dbdatadapter.Updatingrowstatuserror`

This is the error message I get when I update data or when I add and save row in a `DataGridView`. This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    Try
        cnn.Open()
        query = "SELECT EmployeeID, TransactionDate, PreviousBalance, CashOnHand, BankBalance, CheckOnHand, PostDatedCheck, ReturnedCheck, StockOnHand, DamagedStocks, Breakages, GoodStocks, EmptyBottles, Expenses, AccountReceivables, Remittance, TotalAmount FROM SalesmanLedger WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", cbEmployees.SelectedValue)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            dgvSalesman.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        scb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

I get the error in `da.update(ds)`. I need your suggestions with this. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you did not specify an UpdateCommand for the DA.  Type the error msg into Google and the first 4 hits are other SO answers

Comment: What do you mean Plutonix? when i use the da.update the update is part of the intellisence and it didn't give me any red squigly line so i'm thinking this is a sound idea for the compiler.

Comment: I edited my code a bit to like this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = cbEmployees.SelectedValue.... Still no luck. I get the same error.

Comment: Look at your load code.  There, you feed some SQL to a OleDBCommand object to build the SelectCommand the DA uses.  You did **not** create an OleDBCommand object with the SQL Update query, so DA has no idea how to perform an update.

Comment: If I am undestanding you correctly, this is what I have done... 
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            query = "same as query above.."
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = cbEmployees.SelectedValue
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            scb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(ds)
        
    End Sub  This is not giving me the error message anymore but it does not save the changes I create in the cells too.